# Adding image for every fields in a Discord RichEmbed

Tags: discord.js

I am using discord webhook to send some automated, scheduled messages on my channel. I would like to add some image with every field I am using in the embed. My current setup is as follows:

```
hook.login(configs.TEST_WEBHOOK_ID, configs.TEST_WEBHOOK_TOKEN);
Embed.setTitle('MY TITLE HERE');

const fields = [];
    for(const item of data) {
        fields.push({
            name: item.title,
            value: item.detail,
            image: {
                url: `${item.imgsrc}`
            }
        });
    }
Embed.fields = fields;
hook.setPayload(hookcord.DiscordJS(Embed));
```

As you can see I am adding a image property on the field object (this does not work). What's the best way to do this? The images are only links and are served from a web server. Thanks

**EDIT**

I am using `hookcord` package for setting up the hooks and `discord.js` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord provide only **2 image** in **1** embed message.

Its method `.setImage('url')` and `.setThumbnail('url')`, so add image to every field impossible.

> Embed Fields have only 3 fields: name - string , value - string , inline - boolevan.
>   [RichEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=fields) / [Embed Visualizer](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/)

Answer (score 1):

Okay as @Cipher pointed out, there was indeed no way to add image inside a field. Instead, I resorted to creating multiple embeds instead of one. Each embed can take two image urls; one for thumbnail and one for banner at the bottom. I structured my data into multiple embeds and sent them over messages. Note that the limit is 10 embeds per message and you may need to adjust accordingly.

Here's the snippet for adding as embeds:

```
for(let send = 0; send < data.length; send += 10) {
            let tosend;
            // size the embeds to max 10
            if((data.length - send) < EMBEDS_PER_MSG) {
                tosend = data.slice(send, data.length);
            }
            else {
                tosend = data.slice(send, EMBEDS_PER_MSG);
            }
            const embeds = [];
            for(const item of tosend) {
                embeds.push({
                    title: item.title,
                    url: item.link,
                    fields: [
                        {
                            name: 'Description',
                            value: item.detail
                        }
                    ],
                    thumbnail: {
                        url: item.imgsrc
                    },
                    image: {
                        url: item.imgsrc
                    },
                    footer: {
                        text: 'Footer Text'
                    }
                });
            }
            hook.setPayload({ embeds: embeds });
}
```